# What is Cloud Firestore Entity Writes quota?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, quota

I'm on the free Firebase plan, with not too many users, but in the last couple of days I've exceeded my "**Cloud Firestore Entity Writes**" quota.

What puzzles me is that I get two different numbers in my two consoles (at the same time):

1. In Firebase (**Database -> Usage**) I can see **3K** writes (quota = 20K)
2. In GCP (**AppEngine -> Quotas**) I can see 0.06 Million Ops = **60K** ops (quota = 0.02 Million Ops = 20K Ops)

Are these the same (Firebase Writes and GCP Entity Writes)?
If so - why do I see two different numbers?
If not - what is this quota all about?

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot of what you're looking at ?